# Django Modelform - setting field value to foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I created two models in my app: "Prescription" and "Prescription_status." When a user clicks save on the "New_prescription" modelform, I need to add a "Prescription_status" to the "Prescription."

For example, below I'd like to add 'Draft' status (PK=1). I don't want to set a default status. I've been trying everything, what am I missing?? Thanks in advance!

models.py

```
# Static Prescription Status Types
class Prescription_status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status_definition = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.status)

# Prescription Model
class Prescription(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Prescription_status, models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

I saved the following Prescription_status objects to the database, which I'd like to reference as users save or edit prescriptions:

status_id for "Draft" status = 1

status_id for "Ready for Signing" status = 2

status_id for "Signed and Authorized" status = 3

[database chart showing PK for each status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83NEQ.png)

forms.py

```
class PrescriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Prescription
        fields = ('medication', 'quantity', 'directions', 'refills', 'earliest_permitted_fill_date', 'daw',)
        widgets = {
             'earliest_permitted_fill_date': DatePickerInput(), # default date-format %m/%d/%Y will be used

     }
```

views.py

```
def new_rx(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PrescriptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            prescription = form.save(commit=False)
            prescription.status = Prescription_status.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['1'])
            prescription.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = PrescriptionForm()
    return render(request, 'app/new_rx.html', {'form': form})
```

The above results in "NameError: name 'Prescription_status' is not defined." What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Have you imported it `from .models import Prescription_status`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just did that but now I have this error: "    prescription.status = Prescription_status.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['1'])
KeyError: '1'
[09/Jul/2019 03:40:36] "POST /new_rx HTTP/1.1" 500 64402
"

Comment: OK, I fiddled a bit and this seems to work:
prescription.status = Prescription_status.objects.get(pk=1). Thank you!

Comment: Just to let everyone know, bc this was also driving me crazy, you can also use: prescription.status = Prescription_status.objects.get(status="Draft") .